# Cognos Report Studio Prompt Macros

Tags: macros, report, prompt, cognos

Is there a full guide for the use of prompt macros?

I have used a few to filter date and text fields (I found them looking around), I am looking to use a macro prompt with a combo (in this case with static fields).

Examples I used: 
    ORGID=#prompt('OrganizationID')#
    to_date(#sq(prompt('Start_Date','DATE'))#,'YYYY-MM-DD')  (what does sq means btw?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

sq() means surround in single quotes.

The most information I've found is in the Framework Manager guide. This contains info including an explanation of sq

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cfpm/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_fm.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_fm_id10577using_macro.html

I have built my own document from all the fragments on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. How about using a combobox macro? I created a parameter in the prompt page but I can't access it with ?pComboBox?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you drop a combobox on the page, set it's  prompt variable to ?pComboBox?, then whatever value(s) you pick in the combo box will feed into the prompt variable ?pComboBox?, and you can then use that value in a prompt macro. Roughly like this: #prompt('pComboBox','token')#, If you explain further I can add more detail to my answer.

Comment: this link may also be useful for anyone looking for this topic: https://www.packtpub.com/article/use-macros-ibm-cognos-report-studio   it belongs to a book called report studio cookbook